# Background Postioning in CSS on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image (background.jpg) on my website. Appears fine on desktop, but doesn't look right on mobile. What do I change in my stylesheet.css to make the image, I guess, shrink in size to appear similarly to desktop?

Current code:

```
#services-top-desktop {
    background: #fff url(../img/background.jpg) fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#services-top-mobile {
    background: #fff url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: You could try bgStretcher: 
http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

Comment: Using two classes here, I guess I'm asking what changes need to be made to the mobile class...

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses two classes, one for desktop and the other for mobile. Instead, use a generic body class in your css

```
body {

  background-image: url('../img/test.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I need two classes in order for the site to adapt to web vs. mobile browsers obviously...